# How can I protect a hardwood floor against dog claws?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

I just bought a house with new hardwood floors.  One of my dogs is a little wild and keeps sliding and scratching the floors up.  I've tried cutting her nails and she won't wear boots.  Does anybody have any ideas as to how to prevent this?  Is there such a thing as professional hardwood coatings?

Comment: People wax floors, and put plastic "nail caps" on their dogs.  Rugs can also help. If you have the option, laminate flooring often has hardeners in them, including metal powder.  Dogs have more difficulty damaging that kind of floor.

Comment: dogs can be trained. my brother's dog will _instantly_ sit if he whistles at it. might be cheaper to train the dog than replacing the floors or buying fancy rugs to cover up nice hardwood would be.

Comment: Not looking to replace the floors, more looking for a covering of some sort that could reduce the affects of the scratching. @RyanBudney -  thanks for nail cap suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solid answer.  It's a big project, but apply a layer of varnish.  Requires sanding the entire floor, applying varnish, rinse and repeat one more time for best results.

Comment: This will prevent the wood from being damaged for a while,  but it will require regular refinishing. My wife's little ankle biting dog can go down to wood with 4 coats of varathane in a few days but my labs both well into 100 lb + are fairly easy on the floors because they don't dig at it when upset.